# Form tag is not being populated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get reference to my form based on form id using jquery but it is failing to reference the form when I use in developer tools.Any help in much appreciated.

[image]

```
 @model Models.ViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TermsAndConditions", "TermsAndConditions", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post", OnSuccess = "Save" }, new { id = "saveStatus" }))
{
    <div class="row-container">


         /* My UI elements */


    </div>


    @Html.Partial("_SubmitButtonPanel", "coverage-server-message")
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datepicker")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#rdate').datepicker({
            defaultDate: '@Model.RDate',
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'top'
        });

        $('#cdate').datepicker({
            defaultDate: '@Model.CDate',
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'top'
        });
    });

    function CheckSave(data) {

        if (data.success) {
            $('#coverage-server-message').text("Successful save!");
        }
        else {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }

    var formId = '#saveStatus'

</script>
```

Ideally I am expecting some form to be generated with my first line of code.But its not happening.

```
<form action="/[controller]/[method]/1?Length=12" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-success="CheckSaveStatusEndorsements" id="saveStatus" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct to me, you could try something like this to get a specific property.

```
$('#saveStatus').attr('id');
```

That should return the same ID that you are using as your selector.

```
$('#saveStatus').serialize();
```

This should give you all the form data as key value pairs

Comment: I am expecting the form data has  a whole to be passed   to controller for data saving while i programmatically invoke submit in the form

Comment: Try $('#saveStatus').serialize();

Comment: No. I am trying some other method using ajax